# What is the preferred/best way to store parameters in an external config file?

Tags: php, symfony

I completed a project in Symfony2 and am now improving/refactoring it. One small task is to put some parameters/credentials in an external config file.
I know that I can import that file by using:

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
- { resource: parameters.php }
```

or:

```
// app/config/config.php
$loader->import('parameters.php');
```

But I want to know the difference/benefits of using yml, xml or php as an external file. Is one of them ' safer' or 'better' then the other perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice there's no difference, this is rather question what you are used to.

In my opinion `parameters.yml` is just key-value stuff so yml is just perfect for this.
Yml is probably most clear but maybe not most fluent.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094580/configuration-files-in-php-xml-vs-yaml-vs-php-files) question for more general differences between various formats.

Comment: Thanks, I now know there is no big difference but more a matter of what you are used to. The other answer made me decide to go for .php as only developers will touch the specific file.